# Maximum play time for youtube video player playlist

Tags: youtube, timeout, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have not been able to find any documentation if Youtube implements a timeout (max play) feature into its javascript / flash players.  Has anyone ran into this?

My team is running into an issue where we have a playlist running on a tv overnight.  We find that the videos keep freezing at random times (just stop playing).

Per our network team, we don't have any outages, issues, etc;

Is this a possible timeout / max playlist time reached issue per some documentation I missed?

We currently call the `<iframe>` for a playlist and let it run.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any intentional policies that would stop playback after a certain amount of time had passed. My suggestion would be to look into the HTTP requests being generated by the player (fairly easy to do if you're running a standard web browser on a PC that's hooked up to your TV) and see whether the failure occurs when an HTTP request is made that doesn't receive a response (for some reason).

Additionally, add some logging in to your application that detects the `onError` and `onStateChange` events and try to correlate specific events with playback stopping.

Regardless of the root cause, it's possible that you could work around this by detecting PAUSED/ENDED events in the player and using the Player API to explicitly start playback.

Comment: the caveat here is we are running this off a google tv (android / chrome constraints) and have no debugging options. The video freezes randomly at times, and we haven't caught any errors (listener + alert)

Answer (score 1):

Im working in anything like this (for Amazon TV) but only with one video. I make a reload when detect a error. This error are 0 is a exception Error(you can see the events in this [page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=es#Events)). I have another problem, maybe you can help me. I see the video in black and I don't see a solution.

```
function startVideo(player,src){
         player = new YT.Player(player, {
         height: '100%',
         width: '100%',
         videoId: src,

         playerVars: {
                controls: 0,
                showinfo: 0 ,
                modestbranding: 1,
                wmode: "opaque",
                loop: true,
               },
               events: {
                 'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
                 'onError': onPlayerError,
              }
          });
}
function onPlayerError(event){
            var D = new Date();
            var d = millisToTime(D.getTime());
            $("#m").html($("#m").html()+"</br></br> <b>-Error: "+event.data+"</b> -"+d);

            var url = window.location.href;    
            if (url.indexOf('?') > -1){
                   url += '&p=1'
               }else{
                   url += '?p=1'
               }
               window.location.href = url;
            }
```